# Differentiate $\sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}e^\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate $$\ln (\sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}e^\sqrt{x}})$$

Answer (score 5):

Let,

$$y = \sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}e^\sqrt{x}}$$

Taking log on both sides,

$$\log y = \log \sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}e^\sqrt{x}}$$

$$\log y = \sqrt{x}e^\sqrt{x} \log \sqrt{x}$$

Now differentiate using product rule.

Comment: Derivative of (1.2.3) = 1.2.derivative of 3 + 1.3.derivative of 2 + 2.3.derivative of 1

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this will help:

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5Bsqrt(x)%5E(sqrt(x)*e%5E(sqrt(x))),x%5D
```

calculated solution: [Solution from Wolfram Alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECTmg.gif)

Comment: This should be a comment (unless posted by Wolfram Alpha itself).

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as Kanwaljit Singh's answer, let $$y = \sqrt{x}^{\sqrt{x}\,e^\sqrt{x}}$$ and first change variable $x=t^2$ to get $$y = t^{t\,e^t}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(y)=t\,e^t \log(t)\implies \frac{y'}y=\left(t\,e^t \log(t)\right)'$$ Differentiate with respect to $t$ and, later, use $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\times\frac{dt}{dx}$$